# VS2010 Strange ASP.NET Startup Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik, asp.net-development-serv

I have existing VS2010 ASP.NET solution which was working OK. However now when I try to run it, I get some very strange (seemingly random combination of) errors:

- Invalid file name for file monitoring: '[Web App Path]\Controls' (this is a directory)
- Requested registry access is not allowed. (Source: mscorlib - the call Stack says its parent higher up the stack is from System.Web.Compliation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart())
- System.Web.HttpException occurred /  HResult=-2147467259 /  Message=File does not exist.
- Access to the path: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6c9c2bea\84b35c9c\App_Web_cyfzelmo.dll' is denied. (also 
  App_Browsers.dvwnc2tw.dll, App_global.asax.wtigsdou.dll)
- An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) - System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
- Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source [stack parent:      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.LoadCachedPreAppStartAssemblies(string preStartInitListPath)]

**These are only shown if I have Debug/Exceptions/CLR Exceptions (Thrown) set**, however I don't recall seeing them before (I usually always have this option set). I created a blank ASP.NET solution, enabled CLR Exceptions (Thrown) and also got the registry and argument null error - whenever I rebuilt and re-ran the solution.

I have recently installed VS2012 as well, but am not sure if this is a cause. I've also upgraded my Telerik controls - but my blank solution doesn't have them configured.

Any suggestions other than a repair install of VS2010? (Which I'll likely try eventually when I get the time).

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: Ahh yes - it now has a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation must have been corrupt. We re-imaged the machine and re-installed VS2010.